# how to execute procedure with netbeans?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

how can i execute a `procedure` in netbeanse?

I write bellow query but it has error.

```
statement.execute("call customer_fnaem('lisa','test')");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by 'Netbeans' that you mean you want to call a stored procedure from Java. Using JDBC it would be something like the following:

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{ call customer_fnaem(?, ?) }");
proc.setString(1, "lisa");
proc.setString(2, "test");
cs.execute();
```